# Searching for TFS variables File

Tags: tfs-2015

I have 4 to 5 Builds on TFS problem is each Build has 1000+ variables, so all i want is there any xml or any other file so i just import my variables or any other possibles solution without writing variables in each build.

Answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the variables in vNext build definition?

Comment: i think it can be done using power shell script?

Comment: @Eddie can you please tell me more about that "How can i use it?"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use PowerShell script to do this if you are talking about the variables in vNext build.

You can create a PowerShell script with following command:

```
Write-Host "vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

This will create a "testvar" variable with "testvalue" filled. Then you can use it in the later build steps by entering $(testvar).